# open project in delphi as administrator

Tags: delphi, manifest, delphi-xe3

In Delphi XE3 -> project Options -> Application, set Custom Manifest
with C: \ Program Files \ MyProject \ Win7UAC.manifest,
but the project does not open as an administrator if the system is installed in a directory other than C: \ Program Files \ MyProject.

How do I configure the project to open as administrator regardless of the path to be installed?

Win7UAC.manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="orion.exe" version="3.1.0.0" processorArchitecture="*"/>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*" processorArchitecture="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
    <applicationRequestMinimum>  
      <PermissionSet ID="FullTrust" Unrestricted="true" />  
      <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="FullTrust" />  
    </applicationRequestMinimum>    
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista -->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Can you show us your manifest file?

Comment: The installation location has nothing to do with whether or not an app requires elevation.

Comment: I need the path to be dynamic in Project Options -> Application -> Custom Manifest, because I do not know where the user will install the application

Comment: @alice you misunderstand what that option does. The path you specify is where the manifest file is located on your development machine when you compile the project. The content of the manifest is then compiled into the resources of the final EXE that you give to your users. The manifest file does not need to be deployed to the users.

Comment: But when I put project.exe in the same directory as the manifest file, the project runs as an administrator and when I put it in another directory, it does not run as administrator

Comment: Nothing in your manifest is telling Windows that the EXE needs to run as an administrator, so where the EXE is located may influence that decision.  Fix the manifest so the EXE tells Windows to always run it as an administrator regardless of where the EXE is located

Answer (score 4):

Your manifest is missing a `requestedExecutionLevel` element. You need to add that to your `trustInfo` element, eg:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="orion.exe" version="3.1.0.0" processorArchitecture="*"/>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*" processorArchitecture="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <applicationRequestMinimum>
        <PermissionSet ID="FullTrust" Unrestricted="true" />
        <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="FullTrust" />
      </applicationRequestMinimum>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista -->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</assembly>
```